# How to parse data from JSON array coming from FB graph API?

Tags: java, json, processing

I am new to JSON.  I'm working with the [json processing library](https://github.com/agoransson/JSON-processing).  Given a JSON such as:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "John Doe",
         "id": "2980311"
      },
      {
         "name": "Jane Doe",
         "id": "10221412"
      },
      {
         "name": "George Doe",
         "id": "111623489"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "blah" : "blah"
    }
}
```

How can I get the id values.  I've started by trying to get an array to work with:

```
String URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/username/friends?access_token=";
String token = "";
String[] response = loadStrings(URL+token);

if(response != null) {
  JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
  JSONArray data = result.getJSONArray("data");
}
```

And this prints out:

```
JSONObject["data"] not found.
JSONObject["data"] is not a JSONArray.
```

But it's definitely getting the data.  If I print out `response` I see the data.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing a [`JSONObject`](https://github.com/agoransson/JSON-processing/blob/master/src/org/json/JSONObject.java) constructor in that library that accepts `String[]` (the type of your `response` variable). There's `JSONObject(String)` and there's `JSONObject(Object)`. If you pass a `String[]` into `JSONObject`, it'll match the latter, which doesn't (immediately) look to me like it'll do what you want.

I suspect you want to get a single `String` from the URL, which you'd then pass into `JSONObject(String)`, at which point things should start working correctly.

Comment: @mix: Excellent! It was a bit of a shot in the dark as I've not used that library, glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

try with this..

GraphObject responseGraphObject = response.getGraphObject();
              JSONObject json = responseGraphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

```
                      JSONObject sys  = json.getJSONObject("data");
          Log.e("urlimage json",  sys.getString("url"));
```